# How to find 4D simple Rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, rotations

Given angle $\theta$ and a subspace $P\leq M_4(\mathbb{R})$ of dimension 2 (a plane), how do I compute for the simple rotation matrix $M$ of angle $\theta$ that fixes $P$?

I tried finding the entries of $M$ using the images of basis elements of $P$ but it leads nowhere. Also, the example in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_of_rotation#:%7E:text=planes%20of%20rotation.-,Simple%20rotations,rotation%20is%20a%20simple%20rotation.&text=For%20example%20the%20following%20matrix,rotated%20through%20an%20angle%20%CE%B8.) wikipedia page seems to be very specific so I can't relate it to general cases.

Answer (score 1):

Take $\{e_1, e_2\}$ as an orthonormal basis of $P$.  Complement it into a basis $\{e_1, e_2, e_3, e_4\}$ of $\mathbb R^4$. In that basis, the matrix $M$ is

$$M=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & \cos \theta & - \sin \theta\\
0 & 0 & \sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}$$

With this, all points of $P$ are fixed.